# How to read Hex file in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa-touch, hex, nsdata

I have 1 Hex file, i want to read this file and parse it to NSString. 
I used this code to read hex file but it only prinf hex code in console:

```
 -(void)readHexfile
{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"path file"];
    NSLog(@"Patch File: %@",data);
}
```

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: Also, is this for Mac OS X or iOS? Because your tags are conflicting: you have the `osx` tag but also `cocoa-touch`, the later is used on iOS. On Mac, that's just `cocoa`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:` instead of `dataWithContentsOfFile` to read it as NSString.

Answer (score 0):

You'd read that using a [`NSScanner`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (convert your data to a string first using `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` (assuming your text is pure ASCII or UTF-8) or read it directly using [`+[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithContentsOfFile%3aencoding%3aerror%3a)). See also the *String Programming Guide* on [how to use scanners](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Scanners.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000147-BCIEFGHC).

**Edit**: So it seems you want to read a file with null-terminated strings. A naive and inefficient way to do that would be:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"file.path"];
NSMutableArray *strings = [NSMutableArray array];
const char *rawData = [data bytes];
NSUInteger dataLength = [data length];
NSMutableData *currentString = [NSMutableData data];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
    if (rawData[i] == 0) {
       if ([currentString length] > 0) {
           [strings addObject:[[[NSString alloc] initWithData:currentString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease]];
       }
       [currentString release];
       currentString = [NSMutableData data];
    } else {
       [currentString appendBytes:&rawData[i] length:1];
    }
}

// Handle the last string if it wasn't null-terminated.
if ([currentString length] > 0) {
   [strings addObject:[[[NSString alloc] initWithData:currentString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease]];
}

// "strings" now is a list of strings.
```

Comment: I use you suggestion:  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/NETSCN.CFG",sd_url]];
    NSLog(@"Patch File: %@",data);
    NSString *resultSring= [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"resultSring: %@",resultSring);

Comment: but it only show 1 line, when it read to '\0', it not read continue

Comment: @NML611: First, of all, did you mean _binary_ file instead of _hex_ file? The later is a file containing hexadecimal number strings like '42AE7C' or whatever. Next, it's likely the _printing_ stopped at the null byte, not the reading.

Comment: Yes, this is a binary file containing hexadecimal number striings. I want to read this file and check if first byte is 0x01,then i read continue to get string(each string has '\0' terminated) and last I change first byte to 0x02 and rewrite to this file. Can you help me? thanks much

Comment: So what is it? Either it is a _binary_ file containing raw data, *or* it is a _hex_ file that contains text (hex dumps). Please be more precise. From your description, it sounds you really have a _binary_ file. I'll update my answer…

Comment: If i use hex editor it show <31 41 41 42 42 43 43 44 44 45 45 46> on the left, and on the right, it show 1AABBCCDDEEFFTP-LINK-TEST.

Comment: I use your code but it only 1 line in hex file added to strings array, other lines not add to strings array

Comment: my hex data is <31 41 41 42 42 43 43 44 44 45 45 46 46 54 50 2D 4C 49 4E 4B 2D 54 45 53 54 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 44 4C 49 4E 4B 2D 54 45 53 54 2D 54 52 45 4B 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 54 72 65 6B 5F 54 65 73 74 5F 54 50 2D 4C 49 4E 4B 00 00>

Comment: I've just tested it, and apart from one a missing `*` in `NSMutableData *currentString` it does produce the correct output: the array is filled with 39 string, most of which are empty. I've updated the code so that it ignores empty strings. So now I get three strings in the `strings` array.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a thing like a "hex file". Hex, or hexadecimal, is a numerical system that is quite suitable to display binary data in octets (8-bit bytes) in some way suitable for humans.

What you currently do is displaying the description of the NSData object onth the console in hex.

Some quick and dirty hack could be just to use the description of the NSData.

```
NSString *hexString = [data description];
```

This will create some overhead that you could strip of using string manipulation methods. 
There are smater ways that may require more work.

On the contrary, if you are not interested in a hex representation then use `stringWithContentsOfFile` to read the file directly into an NSString object. You can then apply various encodings depending on how your file is actually encoded.

Comment: There is a thing called "hex file": it's files that contain hex dumps of some data, like [Intel HEX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX) format. This used a lot in embedded programming.

Comment: That is a dump. It is stored in octets as nealy every data in modern IT. There is nothing "hex" about it until it is displayed in some hexadecimal representation of the data. That as such may be quite usful. But the data is never hex. It is always binary, regardless whether it represents numbers or characters or statuses or any combination of those.

Comment: If you want to be that strict: there are no text files then, it's also binary.

Comment: Well, that is right. But each data does represent something. No data in the world, that I remember from 25 years on the job, including dumps of several systems, does really represent hex values. Hex is always just used as some convenient way to display octet data in a compact an human redable way independent from their meaning. And that is what I mean. You do not open a hex file and read it. You open a file, read it and display (or use) it in some file specific way. It would be helpful for @NML611 to understand his input as a simple stream of octets. (as far as I understand his challenge).

Comment: In embedded systems programming, the term "hex file" is used a lot and has a very specific meaning like "image file" has to you: they are hex dumps in certain formats and are the most common output of a lot of compilers/linkers/toolchains. We use those when flashing MCUs and EEPROMs. But this discussion doesn't help the OP: Given the comment of the OP to my answer, he has a file which contains null-terminated strings, _maybe_ containing partial hex dumps from the look of it. But it's still unclear to me what that data really is and what he wants to do with it. Not enough information.